# Sidemenu background-color in Ionic-v4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, background, background-color, side-menu

I have a Ionic-v4-app with an side-menu structured like that:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>

      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Now I want the have a background for the whole side-menu (header, list, content, everything).

But it is unnecessary what I try, I don’t get how it is working.

I tried a background color for `ion-menu` and transparent background for `header` and `content`, but also not working.

I know that i had to use i had to use ionic css variables like `--ion-background-color`, but how?

Comment: what your  requirement? you need set background color in ion-menu

Comment: I have set background-color to ion-menu but it is not working. I just see background in menu without any content, but ion-header and ion-content is still white. Want to have it transparent

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe below solution would help you :-)

```
ion-menu {
  --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  --ion-text-color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);

  ion-toolbar {
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
  }

  ion-list {/* optional, but it needs when you use gradient as a background color.*/
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```