# How to change menu background from any page CSS Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to change ion-menu background different for every page but it's not working:

**app.component.html:**

```
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content class="app-content" part="placeholder">
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header lines="full">
            <ion-avatar >
              <ion-img [src]="'./assets/logo.png'"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
             Pyramid to True Love
          </ion-list-header>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="forword" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" >
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
     </ion-app>
```

app.component.scss(Working):

```
ion-menu ion-content{
     --background: #59d36d;
}
```

any.page.scss(Not working):

```
ion-menu ion-content{
     --background: #59d36d;
}
```

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,
Ref : [Sidemenu background-color in Ionic-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311143/sidemenu-background-color-in-ionic-v4)

```
ion-menu {
  --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  --ion-text-color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}
```